# Web Scraping - Using Functions on a Secure Site (rvest)

Tags: css, r

I'm attempting to scrape a site that requires a form to be submitted before getting results.  I'm struggling to understand how it works, let alone syntax and other things.

I have been looking at code posted by other people, and many people use rvest or RSelenium.  I can't seem to get my form to submit properly, and not sure how to go about extracting the results into R once it does submit.

Now, I can't share the specific site that I'm working from, but I've found an analog:

https://gapines.org/eg/opac/advanced

For example, I might need to select "Books" under "Item Type," and "Braille" under "Item Form."  Once the form is submitted, I would need to capture that results page.

Copying from other peoples' code, I have the following:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://gapines.org/eg/opac/advanced"
my_session <- html_session(url) #Create a persistant session
unfilled_forms <- html_form(my_session)
login_form <- unfilled_forms[[2]] # select the form you need to fill
filled_form <- set_values(login_form,'fi:item_type'="Books",'fi:item_form'="Braille")
login_session <- submit_form(my_session,filled_form)
```

When I run the submit_form(), it says "Submitting with 'NULL'."

Once it is submitted, I also want to extract the results, but not sure how to even begin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to visit the response url... `rvest::jump_to(session, session$response$url)`

Comment: Hmm... tried that on my site and got:

Comment: Warning message:
In request_GET(x, url, ...) : Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).